# shadow in svg on hover

Tags: css, svg, hover

I don't see what I'm doing wrong, so perhaps someone else will!

Here goes: I've made a Facebook button in svg. When I hover over the button I would like it to "sink into the background" using a inline shadow.

Here is the svg:

```
    <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 400 400" style="enable-background:new 0 0 400 400;" xml:space="preserve">

     <style type="text/css">
    .st0{fill:#FFE06B;}
    .st1{fill:#F7C411;}
    .st2{fill:#FF9900;}
    g#shadow {display:none;}
    g#shadow:hover {display:block;}
</style>

<g id="layer_1">
    <circle class="st0" cx="200" cy="200" r="200"/>
</g>
<g id="shadow">
    <path class="st1" d="M4,204C4,93.543,93.543,4,204,4c54.211,0,103.375,21.578,139.398,56.602C307.059,23.228,256.246,0,200,0
        C89.543,0,0,89.543,0,200c0,56.245,23.227,107.058,60.602,143.397C25.578,307.374,4,258.211,4,204z"/>
    <g>
        <path class="st1" d="M246.379,103.232v33.333h-18.138c-5.393,0-8.823,1.471-10.539,4.412c-1.226,1.961-1.716,5.392-1.716,10.049
            v15.196h30.883l-3.677,33.579h-27.206v96.815h-39.952v-96.815h-19.608v-33.579h19.608v-20.099
            c0-20.588,7.108-33.824,21.079-39.461c6.863-2.696,12.745-3.431,18.873-3.431H246.379z"/>
    </g>
</g>
<g id="layer_3">
    <g>
        <path class="st2" d="M242.524,99.145v33.333h-18.138c-5.393,0-8.823,1.471-10.539,4.412c-1.226,1.961-1.716,5.392-1.716,10.049
            v15.196h30.883l-3.677,33.579h-27.206v96.815H172.18v-96.815h-19.608v-33.579h19.608v-20.099c0-20.588,7.108-33.824,21.079-39.461
            c6.863-2.696,12.746-3.431,18.874-3.431H242.524z"/>
    </g>
</g>
</svg>
```

The group with ID "shadow" should display when I hover over it, but it doesn't. Who sees my mistake?

Thanx,

Thom

Answer (score 1):

The shadow elements are display:none and are therefore not rendered. There's nothing there to hover over.

This turns on the shadow when you hover anywhere over the button, assuming that's what you want to achieve. There's an additional hidden circle to catch all the events and the foreground is pointer-events: none so it doesn't interfere with the catching of the hover events.

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 400 400" style="enable-background:new 0 0 400 400;" xml:space="preserve">

     <style type="text/css">
    .st0{fill:#FFE06B;}
    .st1{fill:#F7C411;}
    .st2{fill:#FF9900;}
    g#shadow {visibility:hidden;pointer-events:all}
    g#shadow:hover {visibility:visible;}
</style>

<g id="layer_1">
    <circle class="st0" cx="200" cy="200" r="200"/>
</g>
<g id="shadow">
    <path class="st1" d="M4,204C4,93.543,93.543,4,204,4c54.211,0,103.375,21.578,139.398,56.602C307.059,23.228,256.246,0,200,0
        C89.543,0,0,89.543,0,200c0,56.245,23.227,107.058,60.602,143.397C25.578,307.374,4,258.211,4,204z"/>
    <g>
        <path class="st1" d="M246.379,103.232v33.333h-18.138c-5.393,0-8.823,1.471-10.539,4.412c-1.226,1.961-1.716,5.392-1.716,10.049
            v15.196h30.883l-3.677,33.579h-27.206v96.815h-39.952v-96.815h-19.608v-33.579h19.608v-20.099
            c0-20.588,7.108-33.824,21.079-39.461c6.863-2.696,12.745-3.431,18.873-3.431H246.379z"/>
    </g>
    <circle visibility="hidden" cx="200" cy="200" r="200"/>
</g>
<g id="layer_3" pointer-events="none">
    <g>
        <path class="st2" d="M242.524,99.145v33.333h-18.138c-5.393,0-8.823,1.471-10.539,4.412c-1.226,1.961-1.716,5.392-1.716,10.049
            v15.196h30.883l-3.677,33.579h-27.206v96.815H172.18v-96.815h-19.608v-33.579h19.608v-20.099c0-20.588,7.108-33.824,21.079-39.461
            c6.863-2.696,12.746-3.431,18.874-3.431H242.524z"/>
    </g>
</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Please disregard my earlier remark: I hadn't looked well enough. This is perfect. Thanx

Comment: Now this is weird: when I open the svg directly in my browser (both in Firefox and in Chrome) it all works perfectly. When I load the same image in the website (Joomla) there is no hover effect: http://dev.shespeakswithpassionmembership.com/index.php bottom of the page. 

Any thoughts?

Comment: It's displayed via an `<img>` tag. SVG in an image context is not interactive. You'd need to use an `<object>` or `<iframe>` tag instead.

Comment: Learnt something new here. Thanx a lot, Robert! I changed it and it works :-)